# Copy record from 2 MySql tables with relation, but foreign key of second table is a new record id from first table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to copy records from 2 MySql table with relation, but I only can make the second table foreign key as old record id from first table. I want to make the foreign key from second table is new record id from first table.

Here for example (`Id` is auto-increment):

`Teacher` table:

```
Id | Name 
---+------
1    Andy
2    John
```

`Class` table:

```
Id | Class | Teacher_ID
---+-------+-----------
1    A       1
2    B       2
3    C       1
4    D       2
```

I want to make it become like this:

`Teacher` table:

```
Id | Name 
---+-----
1    Andy
2    John
3    Andy
4    John
```

`Class` table:

```
Id | Class | Teacher_ID
---+-------+-----------
1    A       1
2    B       2
3    C       1
4    D       2
5    A       3
6    B       4
7    C       3
8    D       4
```

What SQL query should I use for this?

Comment: Please supply more information.

Comment: Although it's not quite clear what you want maybe this will help: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subqueries.html

Comment: is it one time transformation? or you need this query to execute periodically?

Comment: im already use `insert into Teacher(name)
    select name from Teacher` and `insert into Class(Class, Teacher_ID)
    select Class, TEacher_ID from Class`. But i wanna make `Teacher_ID` update from new record from `Teacher Table`

Comment: why do you need that many teachers? it has no sense

Comment: Sorry for that, but it just example. Its to long if i tell the real problem